# I was programming in YACC, when for a grammar I got a shift reduce conflict. Do I have to worry about this?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

As far as my understanding in the SLR parser itself resolves the shift reduce conflict by using the handles and viable prefixes etc. So why should the shift reduce conflict bother me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conflict means that the parser generated may not accept the entire language described by the grammar, but rather a subset of that language.  If you don't care about not parsing some constructs that are legal according to the grammar, then you can ignore the shift/reduce and reduce/reduce conflicts.

Now sometimes the conflicts are due to ambiguities in the grammar, which means that there are multiple ways of parsing the same thing, and sometimes when that is the case, the conflict can be ignored, as the parser will still parse the entire language.  But not always (in fact its the exception rather than the rule), so in general you need to look at *why* the grammar has a conflict and what effect that has on the parser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about *one*, if it is the else/if conflict. Anything else you should certainly worry about, and it can get very tricky to debug indeed. Fortunately you are doing simple grammars and there are enough working simple examples around that you only need to compare and contrast.